# Cannot set up https on microsoft azure VM

Tags: ssl, https, apache-2.4, azure, owncloud

For over a week now I am trying to set up https to work with my owncloud hosted on a Microsoft Azure virtual machine (ubuntu server 14.04). I am using apache2. I have gone through every single tutorial i have found on the web and also one person on the owncloud forums was trying to help for a while but the preblem is still unsolved.

I am wondering now is there anything unusual about a linux system that is hosted on microsoft azure? Because this ssl setup as far as ive learned for past couple of days should pretty much work out of the box. I am wondering either this has anything to do with the fast that I have added HTTPS frontend after the VM was created, not in the process of its creation. Anyways I am listening to 443 port and i have ssl enabled, I have created the keys pair and turned on the ssl engine.

Also Debian man pages etc. 
Here are my logs and virtual host for ssl:

default-ssl.conf in sites-available:

https://pastebin.com/jvhPpDKa

My rep is to low to post more than 2 links, so here I pase a link to my post from owncloud forums where one can see pastebins with my netstat and acces + errors logs:

https://forum.owncloud.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=26375&start=20#p80237

Im really desperate right now, I have no idea why cant I connect to my server using https... I would really aprichiate all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Appereantly theres a bug in microsoft azure frontends ACLs. I had no reles applied so it means it should allow all trafic on that frontend. Instead it was filterring everything. To fix that i denied a random ip address so a rule to "allow every but this one" would start working. After that i could acces my site with https. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the HTTPS endpoint on your Azure VM? You can check the endpoints when you view the properties of your VM. At the top you will see four items: Dashboard, Monitor, Endpoints and Configure. Click on endpoints and make sure that HTTPS is there. If not, click on the Add at the bottom and add it.

Comment: Yes, i did. I think this might be the case- that even though it is enabled, it doesnt work.

Comment: I noticed that in your netstat that apache is listening on 443, but only tcp6. Maybe try to get it to bind to tcp4 and see if that makes a difference? I guess changing the <VirtualHost *:443> to <VirtualHost 0.0.0.0:443> and restart apache might do it, but I haven't tried.

Comment: After changing virtualhost like you specified, the netstat showed that i am still listening on tcp6. Even though I tried but it didnt help :/. netstat: https://pastebin.com/XM7LPzm7

Comment: See if you can find the Listen 443 option in /etc/apache2/ports.conf and change that also to Listen 0.0.0.0:443

Comment: Now i see port 443 in tcp, but https still doesnt work. https://pastebin.com/a6Ps2uTt

Comment: do you have any other ideas?

Comment: You can check if you can get anything from apache at the server console. Run the command "`curl https://localhost`" or "`curl https://<internal ip address>`" and see if you get anything to download.

Comment: i have tried what u suggested- when curled with localhost it worked, i downloaded the page. However when I curled my public page address (vm.mydomain.com) i got connection timeout.... What does this mean?